# Billing Day Code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to sql but, I'm trying to create code that will look at a Calendar table and determine if the Last Day of Billing Month, (Last field in the table) was the day before the day I am providing.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Select * from Calendar_table (for any given day)
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Is your calendar_table an own table with "running" dates (a tally table)? Which table are you talking about by writing "Last field in the table"? What could be date you provide?

Comment: DATEADD: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following in a parameterized query:

```
DECLARE @pGivenDatetime DATETIME
SET @pGivenDatetime = <your date to test>

SELECT * FROM Calendar_table where DATEDIFF(d, @pGivenDatetime,  [Last Day of Billing Month], ) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your flag column is a date type

```
select * from Calendar_table where date1 > [date provided]
```